# Javascript: move the "view point" of the browser

Tags: javascript, html, css, viewport

I have a page with many out-of-bounds contents and since I set `body{overflow:hidden}`, they are not  outside the viewport. So I want to attach a function to a button which would move the **PoV of the browser** so that the out-of-bounds contents would come into the viewport.

What I can think of now is to set `body{position:relative}` and use jQuery to `animate()` the body instead. But in terms of performance, is there a better way to achieve that?

Comment: You can use [jQuery UI `$.draggable()`](http://jsfiddle.net/userdude/t6CNF/), although the user interaction for reading content (if that's what you're doing on that site) may be a bit wonky. I would probably say look at [`jQuery.scrollTo()`](http://demos.flesler.com/jquery/scrollTo/). It's animation, so you *have to cache your selectors when at all possible for reuse* if you expect performance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try to set `document.documentElement.scrollLeft` and `.scrollTop` to the right amount of pixels so the viewport shows the content you want.

Note: in Firefox, you should set `document.body` instead. For a cross-browser solution, set them both, and one of the couples should remain 0.